# How can I number each line in a \split environment?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have the following code in which all of the x variables need to be aligned and I need each line to be numbered so I can reference it later on in my workings. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0x_1&&&&&                &= 0 \nonumber \\ 
-2x_1& &- 8x_2& &+ 2x_3& &= 0 \\ 
x_1& &- 3x_2& &- x_3&    &= 0 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

For reference the code above gives this result:

[image]

Comment: An `equation`/`split` combination is not the right tool for your formatting job. Use an `alignat` environment instead.

Comment: Hi Mico, I have never used the align environment. Could you give me the code for it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
 0x_1&     &&               &&= 0 \nonumber \\ 
-2x_1&-8x_2&&+2x_3          &&= 0 \\ 
  x_1&-3x_2&&-\phantom{2}x_3&&= 0 
\end{alignat}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!